# Downloading a dynamic webpage as a static html page

Tags: php, html

I am developing a code in PHP where I will have to download the contents in the webpage (http://novosibirsk.e2e4online.ru/shop/catalog/#/category=24) and store the attribute values into the database table,I am using the code below to download the page,

```
$html=file_get_contents('http://novosibirsk.e2e4online.ru/shop/catalog/#/category=24');
```

this page includes dynamic content . But i need the webpage to be saved as a static html page . Is there any PHP function to download a website as a static page ? In either case ,when i inspect a particular element on the page using google chrome , it shows static code for every element .  Or is there any way i can download all the static content through google chrome ? I just need the static content of the webpage to be stored in a variable or a file after downloading . Please help me with this problem !! Thanks in advance!

Comment: your `file_get_contents` will download the rendered page, so it is as static as can be. If by "dynamic" you mean ajax/javascript content, then consider downloading the page with phantom.js or another js server side framework. PHP cannot evaluate the JS code.

Comment: When you use file_get_contents to download a page you now have a static page regardless of how the actual page was generated.

Answer (score 0):

You want "web scraping".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Answer (score 0):

You must use curl and send POST requests to get dynamic contents.
To know what POST requests were sent, you can you Developer Tool of Google Chrome and select tab Network.